# Trouble with defining simple emacs command

Tags: emacs, elisp

*I'm new to emacs and newer to lisp*

I'm trying to set Meta + spacebar to set the mark for highlighting text (at current cursor position).
searching around online and experimenting I've ended up with the command

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") 'push-mark nil nil 1)`

The above command isn't working for me though, I'm getting an "incorrect number of arguments error".

Got the function definition,

  push-mark &optional position nomsg activate

[from elisp manual here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_491.html)

  **Position:**
  nil for position should default to current cursor position

  **nomsg:**
  I don't care about (I think)

  **activate:**
  apparently isn't true by default so I need to set it to...something.

How would I format the command to pass in three values?

*The error is definitely due to the push-mark function call as other functions such as backward-char (which I'm not passing inputs to) work correctly*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `global-set-key` <kbd>RET</kbd> tells you, `global-set-key` takes two arguments: `(global-set-key KEY COMMAND)`

You're passing five arguments: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") 'push-mark nil nil 1)`

Hence "wrong number of arguments".

You can either supply the symbol for a named function, or an anonymous function / lambda.

e.g.: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") (lambda () (interactive) (push-mark nil nil 1)))`

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit to what @phils says:

1. `push-mark` is not a *command*: its definition has no `interactive` spec.  Note that phils's example includes `(interactive)` in the anonymous function, making it a command.
2. Unlike `push-mark`, `push-mark-command`, as its name suggests, is a command.  If you want the effect of `push-mark` then just bind `push-mark-command`, or better yet `set-mark-command`.